# Need help moving an object away from the mouse at the correct rates

Tags: java, 2d, physics

I am new to programming, and I am trying to make a 2d applet that will move a circle or ball away from the mouse. The way I want the physics in this program to work is to make the object act like a ball, and the mouse like a movable hill. When the mouse get closer to the ball, it repels the ball faster and farther away, and when the mouse gets farther away from the ball, the ball slows down and eventually stops moving. I need to take into account both the total distance between the mouse and the object, and the x and y distance so the movement of the object is smooth and more realistic. The biggest problem that I have is that even as the distance between the two points become greater, the rate at which the ball moves away stays relatively constant. Currently the rate is the distance of x or y multiplied by a constant, and divided by the total distance. This more or less works when the mouse moves closer to the object, and the rate increases as it should, but it fails when the mouse moves away. I want the rate to decrease and eventually become 0 when the mouse moves away, but in my current set up the x distance will also increase as the distance increases, and the rate will not decrease as much as I want it to, if at all. The way I have it now probably needs to be scraped all together, and thanks for the help.

```
    public void mouseMoved (MouseEvent e) 
{
    //distance between x coord
    xd=e.getX()-x;
    //distance between y coord
    yd=y-e.getY();
    //total distance between mouse and ball
    d=Math.sqrt((Math.pow(xd,2))+(Math.pow(yd,2)));

    //rate of x change
    xrate=(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xd,2))*4)/(d);
    //rate of y change
    yrate=(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(yd,2))*4)/(d);

    //determines movement of ball based on position of the mouse relative to the ball
    if(xd>0)
    {
        x=x-((int)(xrate));
    }
    if(xd<0)
    {
        x=x+((int)(xrate));
    }
    if(yd>0)
    {
        y=y+((int)(yrate));
    }
    if(yd<0)
    {
        y=y-((int)(yrate));
    }

    //updates x and y coords of ball
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: So basically like a repelling magnet?

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
//rate of x change
xrate=(1.0/(d))*20; //20 is just a random constant I guessed
//rate of y change
yrate=(1.0/(d))*20;
```

Comment: Also you'd have to check to make sure you don't try to divide by 0

Answer (score 0):

You just did wrong math.

```
 //total distance between mouse and ball
 d=Math.sqrt((Math.pow(xd,2))+(Math.pow(yd,2)));
 //rate of x change
 xrate=(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xd,2))*4)/(d);
```

Think about this :

If you only move on the x cord, will simply make yd equals 0 and d=|xd|

So xrate = |xd|*4/(d) = d*4/d = 4.

There is a easy way to accomplish your task, just make xrate and yrate related with xd and yd.

You can try this :

```
if(xd==0){
  xd = 0.1;//minimum distance
}
if(yd==0){
  yd = 0.1;
}

xrate = (1/xd)*10; // you can change number 100 for proper speed
yrate = (1/yd)*10;
x = x - xrate;
y = y - yrate;
```

Hope this can help.